# Starting an Activity/Service before BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I'm writing a remote lockscreen, with some additional features. The only problem I am facing is that, if I register a broadcastreceiver on BOOT_COMPLETED on slower phones, it takes ~10 seconds until the activity/service is started. Even with highest possible priority. So my question is:

- Is there another way than register on BOOT_COMPLETED to start an app after restarting?

I thought of a way to bind the Activity/Service on the standard lockscreen, but is this even possible?